# 1:1 copy with dd

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I need to get a copy of an HDD that is a real 1:1, I mean not just the filesystem but also the geometry and the partition table and everything in between.

if I'll just use

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/tmp/file
```

this will generate what I'm looking for ?

Comment: Only if the disk is sane. It will also be inefficient because `dd` reads only 512 bytes at a time. Add `conv=noerror,sync` to copy disks with errors (or better use `ddrescue`) and use bigger block size otherwise to improve performance (or better, use `ddrescue`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this should be fine. Be sure to unmount your disk first and make sure there is enough space in the target directory. `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` in memory and not on disk on some systems, look at the output of `mount` to check.

On a root shell you can also simply do:

```
cat /dev/sdb >/tmp/file
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, just copy it:

```
cp /dev/sdb /tmp/sdb.img
```

Please note Stephane's comment below for a potential benefit of using `cp`.

Comment: `cp --sparse=always` with GNU `cp` could help you save space.

Comment: Will this copy boot loaders and partition tables?

Comment: @Sparhawk - it will copy the entire contents of `/dev/sdb` to `/tmp/sdb.img`. If `/dev/sdb` contains a partition table and boot loaders then yes. Be careful about using the same disk image twice in a single configuration though - UUIDs aren't unique for nothing.

Comment: Okay, then you can copy back with `cp /tmp/sdb.img /dev/sdb`? Also, is there an advantage to using `cp` over `dd`?

Comment: @Sparhawk - `cp` is at least simpler. You *can* likely achieve much the same performance and results using `dd`- and with GNU `dd` even  something akin to `--sparse=always` - but it will take some tweaking. `cp` is pretweaked. And yes, you should be able to simply `cp` the image back over the `/dev/`ice but any such action will, of course, be completely destructive to whatever was on the `/dev/`ice before you did.

Comment: @Sparhawk, a good `cp` implementation will automatically optimise the block size, so will be faster than `dd`. Don't use `--sparse=always` when you copy to a disk though, only when copying to a file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas For me, `cp --sparse=always` created an identical file to `dd`. I wonder if it works for volumes, but not whole devices?

Answer (score 1):

There is an informative article on the Arch distro wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_Cloning)